# Laravel nesting child views

Tags: php, laravel

All of us know that Laravel allows us to nest child view easily:

```
return View::make("myView")->nest("sidebar", "sidebar");
```

But what if I need the sidebar in my every view. That seems awkward to nest it each time. specially that there are many nested views such as : footer, header, navigation, sidebar.

Is there a way to have a nested view without explicitly declaring it each time?

I don't want to use **Blade Engine**.

Comment: Maybe view composer ?

Comment: I appreciate if you tell about view composer a little more as an answer..at least a vote-up is yours

Comment: I'd rather go a different way: create a so-called `Layout view` having `footer`, `header`, `sidebar` etc. views nested, then fill it with a content of a view for the given route.

Comment: @MT-Developer Why not wrap them in a method which has default nested views and call main view by passing parameter for the main view.

Comment: @RahilWazir thanks it had came to my mind but I thought perhaps Laravel has already predicted this natively without Blade intervening or an extra method to come. Thanks all I got it'

Comment: why not just include it in the layout?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can attach a view composer to the layout specified in your `BaseController`.

Something like:

```
View::composer('layout', function($view)
{
    $view->with('sidebar', 'sidebar');
});
```

You can put this code on routes.php or create a composers.php in app folder.